# The car does not belong in the city or into the city

Tags: prepositions

> The car does not belong in/into the city

I’m having a discussion with a German speaker that’s convinced the correct sentence is “belong into the city”. I am convinced in any case it’s “belong in the city”.

Which one is correct? Is there meaning the same?

Comment: *Into* means "**motion** into".  But if the car is just *existing*, not moving, then referring to motion doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear what you are trying to say.

If you mean "This car should not be in the city" you could say

> This car doesn't belong in the city.

If you mean "This car is not owned by the city" you could say

> This care doesn't belong to the city.

You would be unlikely to use "belong into"